# Debugging Application - llegal characters in path

Tags: c#

I'm making `HttpWebResponse` to an API, the return data is in `JSON` format.

I receive no errors when compiling, but when I run the application I receive the following error message:

> illegal characters in path

I think the problem is something to do with the **//Get Response**

```
 private void RequestVehicleData()
    {
        string make = "";
        string postcode = "";

        string registration = (string)(Session["regNo"]);
        make = txtmake.Text;
        postcode = txtpostcode.Text;


        //Make Request
        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(String.Format("https://www.check-mot.service.gov.uk/api/v1/mot-history/{0}/{1}/", registration, make));
        httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json";

        //Get Response
        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

            String vehicle = File.ReadAllText(result);
            Vehicle v1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Vehicle>(vehicle);

            lblColor.Text = v1.vehiclecolour;
            lblModel.Text = v1.vehiclemodel;
            lblReg.Text = v1.Registration;

        }
    }
```

Comment: How about you do basic debugging first?

Comment: [use the debugger](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-A-Beginn) to find out what `String.Format("https://www.check-mot.service.gov.uk/api/v1/mot-history/{0}/{1}/", registration, make)` returns

Comment: Just used the site to find out my MOT has nearly expired, thanks :)

Comment: You should use [`WebUtility.UrlEncode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.urlencode(v=vs.110).aspx) to encode the registration and make strings before you append them to the URL.

Comment: The odds that File.ReadAllText() can work are exceedingly low, a web server doesn't know beans about the kind of files that you have stored on your disk drive.  What you *meant* to do is unguessable.  Maybe you didn't eliminate test code well enough, passing *result* to DeserializeObject() would be the most logical approach.

Comment: Andrey - difficult to debug, the app is on a remote server, unable to hit the API directly when debugging as the API will only respond to the hosting server IP address.

Comment: Hans Passant - I am passing the result to DeserializeObject(), do ou mean pass the result directly to DeserializeObject()

Comment: If you cannot debug, add extensive logging to your application so you can gather logs from the remote server.